# Explanation needed for missing rows with left join and count()

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

Can someone please help me understand the following behavior that occurs when I add a WHERE clause to a query that has a LEFT JOIN with COUNT(*)?

I have two tables:

```
TABLE 1: customers
customer_id | name
------------------
1 | Bob
2 | James
3 | Fred

TABLE 2: orders
order_id | customer_id | order_timestamp
----------------------------------------
1000 | 1 | 2011-01-01 00:00
1001 | 1 | 2011-01-05 00:00
1002 | 2 | 2011-01-10 00:00
```

Now the following query tells me how many orders each customer placed:

```
select c.customer_id, count(o.order_id)
from customers c
left join orders o using (customer_id)
group by 1

customer_id | count
-------------------
1 | 2
2 | 1
3 | 0
```

This works great BUT if I add a WHERE clause to the query, the query no longer outputs  counts of zeroes for customers who did not place any orders even though I'm doing a LEFT JOIN:

```
select c.customer_id, count(o.order_id)
from customers c
left join orders o using (customer_id)
where o.order_timestamp >= '2011-01-05'
group by 1

customer_id | count
-------------------
1 | 1
2 | 1
```

Now if I move the WHERE condition as part of the LEFT JOIN like the following, I get back my zero counts for customers who did not place orders:

```
select c.customer_id, count(o.order_id)
from customers c
left join orders o on (c.customer_id = o.customer_id) and (o.order_timestamp >= '2011-01-05')
group by 1
```

I'm confused at why the second query does not work, but the third one does? Can someone please provide me with an explanation? Also not sure if this matters, but I'm using postgres. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because NULL is not greater than or equal to anything; If you change your WHERE clause to `where o.order_timestamp is null or o.order_timestamp >= '2011-01-05'` then you will get the same behavior as your join clause limit.

Note though - I would recommend the join clause approach, as it matches more closely what you are trying to do.  Also the change to the WHERE clause I mentioned above will only work if the order_timestamp column is not nullable -- if it is then you should use a different column for the null check (eg, `where o.primarykey is null or o.order_timestamp >= '2011-01-05'`).

Comment: Thanks - that does work! However I'm still confused. If the WHERE clause fails, shouldn't zero rows for that particular customer_id be joined which means count(*) will be zero?

Comment: Any time the where clause returns false for a particular row, that row will be excluded from the result set; This is happening on the final result set, not an in-between result set (when you apply the clause to your join, then it does what you are suggesting).

Comment: The difference between the WHERE clause and the JOIN clauses that you show is that when you put additional constraints on the left join clause, you aren't changing the fact that the table on the left of the join still returns, it just doesn't get matched to a row from the table on the right.  When you use the where clause, the join has already occurred and now you are choosing which of the joined rows you want to have returned.

Comment: One major implication of adding the constraint to the WHERE clause is that the query will have to consider ALL `o.order_timestamp` values to determine if one is null. At least in my case, this effectively broke indexes in my table of 3 million rows. Adding the constraint to the JOIN did not have negative performance implications.

Comment: Correction: the condition `where o.primarykey is null or o.order_timestamp >= '2011-01-05'` performs well and is more flexible than adding a condition to the JOIN clause. Using the JOIN clause can be difficult to integrate into views.

Answer (score 6):

Placement of filter criteria matters when dealing with OUTER joins (RIGHT, LEFT).  Criteria in the ON clause of an OUTER JOIN is applied before the JOIN; criteria in the WHERE clause is applied *after* the JOIN -- applied against the resultset that uses the JOIN.

```
   SELECT c.customer_id, 
          COUNT(o.order_id)
     FROM CUSTOMERS c
LEFT JOIN ORDERS o ON o.customer_id - c.customer_id
                  AND o.order_timestamp >= '2011-01-05'
 GROUP BY c.customer_id
```

#### Ordinals

Ordinals, meaning using a numeric value that refers to the numeric position of the columns in the SELECT clause, is not a recommended practice.  If anyone changes the query -- say to add a column -- it could drastically affect your query.

Comment: for me, I was missing the `GROUP BY`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Chirs is right, null is not greater than or equal to anything. So when you include your condition in where clause it applies on final view(table) of result generated by left join,
in this result your condition removes row which has time stamp null.

However when you apply same condition during doing a join, condition applies only on order table and than left join performed. So it does not remove rows which has time stamp null.

So, in third query condition applied before final table generated and in second query condition applied after final table generated